# In One To Many Relationship, How Do I Return JUST The Many entities Given A Specific Entity On The One Side

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two two tables A and B that have a one to many relationship. I want to return all the B records (as a list) associated with the most recent A record that has a specific `UserId`. I have the following `LINQ` statement but it's only returning the first of the B entities (assuming it's the `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, just not sure what to replace it with) instead of all of the B records as a list associated with the given A record. I had another `LINQ` query that worked but it made two DB calls, so I was given this to make it one DB call (good thing I tested it). I'm sure it's a very basic thing I'm missing here I'm just spinning my wheels at this point:

```
var test = await _db.RecordA
.Where(A=> A.UserId == 1) //A UserId can be associated with multiple A records
.OrderByDescending(A => A.DateGenerated)
.Take(1) //I want the most recent A record
.Select(A => A.RecordB.ToList()) //There could be many B records associated with the given A record, hence the lazy loading
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?  I added .Include() and .SelectMany()

```
var test = await _db.RecordA
                    .Include(A => A.RecordB)
                    .Where(A => A.UserId == 1)
                    .OrderByDescending(A => A.DateGenerated)
                    .Take(1)
                    .SelectMany(A => A.RecordB)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `Include` is not necessary. It's ignored.

Comment: It looks like I was using the wrong test A record (it wasn't the most recent for the user) so the LINQ I posted was correct, but you also provided another correct solution so I'll mark as correct. I just ran simple StopWatch timers on both and they seem to be pretty much the same in terms of time taken. Not sure about memory though but I'll run that separately. Thank you!